# Too many characters in character literal?

Tags: asp.net, character, literals

Can you tell me please what is wrong with this code??? About to getting crazy!!!

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClick="DivAc('griddiv')" Font-Size="Smaller"  runat="server" CommandName='<%# Eval("harf").ToString().ToUpper()%>'><%# Eval("harf").ToString().ToUpper() %></asp:LinkButton>
```

Error: Too many characters in character literal... :(

Comment: Did you try to replace the inner text, by a text property : `<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClick="DivAc('griddiv')" Font-Size="Smaller"  runat="server" CommandName='<%# Eval("harf").ToString().ToUpper()%>' Text='<%# Eval("harf").ToString().ToUpper() %>' />` ?

Comment: By the way, you can't use generic function for OnClick event handler.

Comment: Hi there people, thanks for your quick replies but I guess, problem is because of this : OnClick="DivAc('griddiv')" because when I remove this part it works???...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Is  `DivAc('griddiv')` a javascript function?
Then you have to use `OnClientClick` instead of `OnClick`.

`OnClick` is reserved for .NET functions. With `OnClientClick` you generates the OnClick-attribute in HTML.

This is probably a bit confusing.

So this is what you have to do:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClientClick="DivAc('griddiv')" Font-Size="Smaller"  runat="server" CommandName='<%# Eval("harf").ToString().ToUpper()%>'><%# Eval("harf").ToString().ToUpper() %></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Thanks Mathieu... Sorry this is my fault :(

Answer (score 13):

The immediate issue is that you placed a **string** (griddiv) in **character** quotes (a single quote, in C#, is for a single character only). You would need to write something like `OnClick="DivAc(\"griddiv\")"`

BUT

OnClick is a server-side event handler that takes the name of a public or protected function that takes (object,EventArgs) and returns void. So this won't compile anyway.

Where is DivAc? In JavaScript? If so, you want OnClientClick, in which case you can leave the single and double quotes as they are.

Comment: Thanks sq33G Onclientclick solve the issue... All my fault sorry for occupying... Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I think that your error is here:

```
CommandName='<%# Eval("harf").ToString().ToUpper()%>'><%# Eval("harf").ToString().ToUpper() %></asp:LinkButton>
```

I think that its should be:

```
CommandName='<%# Eval("harf").ToString().ToUpper()%'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Your suggestion will result in no text for the LinkButton.

Comment: Hi there people, thanks for your quick replies but I guess, problem is because of this : OnClick="DivAc('griddiv')" because when I remove this part it works???...