# Error: too many characters in character literal asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting this error while binding data to data list 
too many characters in character literal asp.net

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="android.aspx.cs" Inherits="finalproject.android" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
.style1
{
    width:900px;
}
.style2
{
    width:633px;
    text-align:left;
}
.style4
{
    width:185px;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="modelid" 
        style="text-align: center; color: #333333;" RepeatColumns="3"
        Width="283px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" CellPadding="3" 
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" 
    CellSpacing="1" >
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#E7E7FF" />
        <ItemStyle BackColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black" />
        <ItemTemplate>
            <br />
            <div align="left"></div>
            <table cellspacing="1" class="style4" style="border:1px ridge #9900FF">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border-bottom-style:ridge; border-width: 1px; border-color: #000000">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%# Eval('brand') %>"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="252px"
                            ImageUrl="<%# Image %>" style="margin-left: 0px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        ModelID<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="<%# Eval('modelid') %>"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
                            CommandArgument="<%# Bind('ModelID') %>" Text="Add to Cart" Width="100%" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="1px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#9471DE" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:DataList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VISHConnectionString2 %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Image], [modelid], [brand] FROM [adddetails]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table align="left" class="style2">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" style="color: #333333"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

I'm getting this error while binding data to data list 
too many characters in character literal asp.net

Comment: Change from this `Text="<%# Eval('modelid') %>"` to this `Text='<%# Eval("modelid") %>'` throughpout your page. After **Text=** you need to use single inverted commas and while binding in **Eval** use double inverted comma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"too many characters in character literal" is caused by having a char-literal with too many characters in it.

You have probably mixed up the `'`-character and the `"`-character.

The error probably lies in your "android.aspx.cs"-file rather than the .aspx-file that you have provided.

Could you provide the code for that as well?

Well, your problems are right here:

```
<%# Bind('ModelID') %>
```

Replace your single-quotes with double-quotes and you will be golden!

```
<%# Bind("ModelID") %>
```

Same goes for all your Evals/Binds

Also see these questions:

[Why I'm getting CS1012: "Too many characters in character literal" and CS0019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600191/why-im-getting-cs1012-too-many-characters-in-character-literal-and-cs0019)

[Too many characters in character literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912819/too-many-characters-in-character-literal)

Comment: Are you sure you did that for all your evals and binds?

Comment: Could you post your CodeBehind as well? the "android.aspx.cs"-file.

Comment: Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

Source Error:


Line 33:                 <tr>
Line 34:                     <td style="border-bottom-style:ridge; border-width: 1px; border-color: #000000">
Line 35:                         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%# Eval("brand") %>"></asp:Label>
Source File: /android.aspx    Line: 35

Comment: I'm not quite sure you can set a attribute via an `Eval` on a server tag, change the `asp:Label` to a `<label><%# Eval("brand") %></label>` or set the `Text`-property of the label from the CodeBehind.

Answer (score 1):

I think the origin of the error is:

```
Eval('brand')
```

It tries to convert brand to a character and fails with that error.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="android.aspx.cs" Inherits="finalproject.android" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
.style1
{
    width:900px;
}
.style2
{
    width:633px;
    text-align:left;
}
.style4
{
    width:185px;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="modelid" 
        style="text-align: center; color: #333333;" RepeatColumns="3"
        Width="283px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" CellPadding="3" 
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" 
    CellSpacing="1" >
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#E7E7FF" />
        <ItemStyle BackColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black" />
        <ItemTemplate>
            <br />
            <div align="left"></div>
            <table cellspacing="1" class="style4" style="border:1px ridge #9900FF">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border-bottom-style:ridge; border-width: 1px; border-color: #000000">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%# Eval('brand') %>"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="252px"
                            ImageUrl="<%# Image %>" style="margin-left: 0px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        ModelID<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="<%# Eval('modelid') %>"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
                            CommandArgument="<%# Bind('ModelID') %>" Text="Add to Cart" Width="100%" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="1px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#9471DE" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:DataList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VISHConnectionString2 %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Image], [modelid], [brand] FROM [adddetails]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table align="left" class="style2">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" style="color: #333333"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Regardless of the validity of your answer, or any new standards it might hold. You should explain what your answer is, why it works, why is it better. What has updated/changed over the years (with older answers). So a reader can understand why your answer is an actual answer.