# Too many characters in character literal error with embed tag in aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I'm struggling with a piece of code and getting error when using this code. what is the correct way to append Eval in this code ?

when I used

```
src='https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=<%# Eval("InvoiceFilePath") %>'
```

It shows that embed tag must end with "/", when I close embed tag, the embed behavior doesn't work as expected.

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View files">  
        <ItemTemplate>  
<embed src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=<%# Eval('InvoiceFilePath') %>" runat="server" width="100" height="75">

         </ItemTemplate>  
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Use this (notice the single and double quotes): `<embed src='https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=<%# Eval("InvoiceFilePath") %>' ... />`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: too many characters in character literal asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29185120/error-too-many-characters-in-character-literal-asp-net)

Comment: It doesn't help. I have updated my issue in Question

Comment: Just remove both dots & trailing slash, adjust the `src` element to current embed tag. The `... /` just marks the end of tag, in `<embed>` tag no need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it must work.

```
<asp:templatefield headertext="View files">  
        <ItemTemplate>  
<embed src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url='<%#Eval("InvoiceFilePath") %>' " runat="server" width="100" height="75">

         </ItemTemplate>  
   </asp:templatefield>
```